# Shell game with probability$ = 0.42$

Tags: probability, game-theory

Let’s say we have a game where we win with probability $p=0.42$ and lose with $q=1-p$. Winning in the shell game has a probability of $0.33$.
I now want to construct a series of bets between a minBet and maxBet so that I make profit. I have the constraint that the longest loss-sequence is not longer than $10$.

Is there a way of generating the best series?
How can I make use of the fact that my longest sequence is $10$?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Maybe it's just me, but you may need to clarify. What exactly do you mean with `now want to construct a series of bets between a minBet and maxBet so that I make profit.` and `I have the constraint that the longest loss-sequence is not longer than 10.`

Comment: Ah, I guess it's just because I didn't know of the [shell game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_game). It might be easier the question if one already knows the rules.

Comment: Does the game have a probability of winning of $0.42$ or $\frac13$? Are the payoffs evens or $2:1$? If you cannot lose more than $10$ in a row then is each game independent?

Comment: In each round, I place a bet between min and max bet. I then win the round with a probability of 0.42. If I win, I win what I bet and if I loose, the money is lost.

Comment: The chance of winning a shell game is $0$ once the operator decides it's time for you to start losing.

Comment: Well, let's move away from the shell game then. The rules are that I can vary my bet between min and maxBet. My assumption is that there will not be a loss series longer than 10. After I place my bet, I win (p=0.42) or loose.

Comment: @jbuchel: If you assume that "there will not be a loss series longer than 10", then you have to discard the (usually tacit) assumption that successive rounds are _independent_, and then knowing the probability for each round separately is not enough to determine how the game you're talking about works.

Comment: if the winning probability < 0.5, and the payoff is even, you generally cannot make money.  however in your special case you can use the DEPENDENCE of successive games (as noted by @HenningMakholm) to your advantage if you know the form of the dependence.  at least you can do this: bet minBet everytime until you see 10 losses in a row, then bet maxBet the next time because you're "guaranteed" to win (so you assume).  if $\frac{maxBet}{minBet}$ is very large you have a money-making strategy here.